# C# IP Address always ::1

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip

I've tried something explained below, somehow, IP Address is always ::1, on both local and server side,

Here are the codes, I tried;

```
m_CallerIP = string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.ServerVariables["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]) ? req.UserHostAddress : req.ServerVariables["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
string Port = string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.ServerVariables["HTTP_CLIENTPORT"]) ? req["HTTP_CLIENTPORT"] : req.ServerVariables["CLIENTPORT"];

string asd2 = String.IsNullOrEmpty(req.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]) ? req.UserHostAddress : req.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
string asd23 = String.IsNullOrEmpty(req.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]) ? req.UserHostAddress : req.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

string asd4 = req.UserHostAddress;

IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(m_CallerIP);
IPAddress address1 = IPAddress.Parse(asd2);
IPAddress address2 = IPAddress.Parse(asd23);
IPAddress address3 = IPAddress.Parse(asd4);
```

Is there anyone to know why and how to solve it ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I've tried it, still ::1

Comment: Are you accessing the server from a different machine?

Comment: @ChristophK yes I already tried this.

Comment: @NewPHPer  for `localhost` it will be always `::1` , but for the external , i want to know how actually you are acessing

Comment: Can you show us the URL you are using to load your web page?

Comment: @mjwills it is like; "https:blabla.blablablabank.co.uk/orderFund.aspx"

Comment: It is odd that there is no `/` after `https:`. Is that website running on your machine, or a different machine?

Answer (score 0):

The code bellow works for me.

When I run the app in localhost I always get ::1. But, it works greate on server side. The app is running in Azure.

```
string ip = "";

ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
    ip = ip.Split(',').Last().Trim();
else
    ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];

if (ip == "::1")
    ip = "";

if (ip.IndexOf(':') > 0)
    ip = ip.Substring(0, ip.IndexOf(':'));

return ip;
```